# Extracting elements from emmGrid of emmeans R package

Tags: r, extract, emmeans

I wonder how to extract `emmean`  and `SE` columns from `emmGrid`  of `emmeans` `R` package. MWE is given below.

```
library(emmeans)
warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)
Test <- emmeans(warp.lm,  specs = "wool")

Test
wool   emmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 A    31.03704 2.105459 48 26.80373 35.27035
 B    25.25926 2.105459 48 21.02595 29.49257

Results are averaged over the levels of: tension 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

class(Test)
[1] "emmGrid"
attr(,"package")
[1] "emmeans"
```

Comment: Hi MYaseen208. We tend to prefer succinct questions here, so if you can trim any non-essential material, that is appreciated by editors and readers. You've added notes about your future appreciation to around ~170 questions, and it's not necessary. Assume we know that you will (highly) appreciate help! Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`summary(Test)` gives a data.frame instead.

```
class(summary(Test))
```

> ```
> [1] "summary_emm" "data.frame"
> ```

So one can do:

```
summary(Test)$emmean
```

> ```
> [1] 31.03704 25.25926
> ```

And

```
summary(Test)$SE
```

> ```
> [1] 2.105459 2.105459
> ```

To actually get a new subsetted data.frame, you need to explicitly coerce to class data.frame:

```
as.data.frame(summary(Test))[c('emmean', 'SE')]
```

> ```
>     emmean       SE
> 1 31.03704 2.105459
> 2 25.25926 2.105459
> ```

Comment: Note emmeans 1.1 added an `as.data.frame` method. So `as.data.frame(Test)` will do the job.

Comment: Just a note: for pairwise comparisons, `summary(pairs(Test))$p.value` will give you the p-values. This is particularly useful when performing a large amount of pairwise comparisons as you can then simply extract p values inferior to 0.05 (or your favorite arbitrary significance threshold) with `which()`.

Comment: Dear Axeman, apologies for pinging, do you know why in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61903460/eff-size-from-package-emmeans-in-r-not-returning-effect-sizes) `emmeans`  doesn't return  any output?

Comment: What about if you added a cld() statement and wanted to pull out group to make a table? So instead of Test <- emmeans(warp.lm,  specs = "wool") it was Test <- cld(emmeans(warp.lm, specs = "wool")? summary(Test)$group does not work in this situation