# package emmeans in R not returning effect sizes

Tags: r, regression, lme4, mixed-models, emmeans

I'm following [this tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html#pairwise) as well as `?eff_size` from package `emmeans` to compute `eff_size()` for my regression model below.

But I get the error: `need an object with call component` from the `eff_size()` call. Am I missing something?

```
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)
h <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hkil/m/master/h.csv')
h$year <- as.factor(h$year)

m <- lmer(scale~year*group + (1|stid), data = h)

ems <- emmeans(m, pairwise ~ group*year, infer = c(T, T))

eff_size(ems, sigma = sigma(m), edf = df.residual(m))
# `Error: need an object with call component`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you tying for this? The object called should be a vector.

```
m <- lmer(scale~year*group + (1|stid), data = h)

ems <- emmeans(m, c("group","year"), infer = c(T, T))

eff_size(ems, sigma = sigma(m), edf = df.residual(m))
```

Output:

```
 contrast  effect.size    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 C,0 - T,0      0.7289 0.224 507    0.289    1.169
 C,0 - C,1     -2.0011 0.134 507   -2.263   -1.739
 C,0 - T,1     -1.2370 0.229 507   -1.687   -0.787
 C,0 - C,2     -3.1640 0.161 507   -3.481   -2.847
 C,0 - T,2     -3.1173 0.261 507   -3.630   -2.605
 T,0 - C,1     -2.7300 0.239 536   -3.199   -2.261
 T,0 - T,1     -1.9659 0.159 536   -2.279   -1.653
 T,0 - C,2     -3.8929 0.257 536   -4.397   -3.388
 T,0 - T,2     -3.8462 0.218 536   -4.275   -3.417
 C,1 - T,1      0.7642 0.232 558    0.308    1.220
 C,1 - C,2     -1.1628 0.139 558   -1.436   -0.889
 C,1 - T,2     -1.1162 0.253 558   -1.614   -0.619
 T,1 - C,2     -1.9270 0.244 572   -2.406   -1.448
 T,1 - T,2     -1.8803 0.193 572   -2.259   -1.502
 C,2 - T,2      0.0467 0.258 634   -0.460    0.554

sigma used for effect sizes: 63.67 
Degrees-of-freedom method: inherited from kenward-roger when re-gridding 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: Do you know what kind of effect size is that? They don't explain that in the description of the function. The calculation seems like a cohen's D for me, but the scale is far different.

Comment: I could see the log transformation here in the source code, logobj = regrid(object, transform = "log"). The effect size is based on the transformed values, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Sorry, @Mohanasundaran, My question was referring to "how do I call this effect size?" Is it akin to Cohen's D? By what you're saying, is there a log effect size? how do I call it?
There is no reference in the function description leading to any theoretical definition of what the function is doing.

Comment: According to this vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html) it is actually Cohen's d.